# Querry on using command "SED" for replacing text in bash shell

Tags: shell-script, sed

While using the command "sed" for find and replace, I wanted to know how one could find a constant and replace it with a variable inside the quotation syntax of sed?

I wanted to replace constant 3 with variable name "hourid"
Here is what I tried.

```
sed -i 's@3@hourid$@g' file_name.txt
```

I want to know how to provide a right syntax for replacing variable "hourid"

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i "s/3/$hourid/g" file_name.txt
```

Or

```
sed -i 's/3/'"$hourid"'/g' file_name.txt
```

Comment: This is identical to the dupe's answers (but lacks any explanation).